Azure HTTP function throwing socket error getting oath token
I created an HTTP function in Azure, to receive webhooks and write them to a Service Bus queue.  I tested it locally with Postman and it worked perfectly.  Now I've deployed it to Azure and its failing using the Test/Run feature.  Here is what I'm seeing in App Insights

I don't know why I'm getting a socket error, most SOs I read applies to HTTP Client exhausting available sockets, but I'm not creating a client.
I'm using a System Assigned Managed Identity in the function app to give it access to the Service Bus.
Here is the code:
 public static class AdobeWebhook
 {
     
     [FunctionName("AdobeWebhook")]
     public static async Task<IActionResult> Run(
         [HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Function, "get", "post", Route = null)] HttpRequest req,
         ILogger log)
     {

         var requestBody = string.Empty;
         using (var reader = new StreamReader(req.Body))
         {
             requestBody = reader.ReadToEnd();
         }
                     
         var config = new ConfigurationBuilder()
             .AddJsonFile("local.settings.json", optional: true, reloadOnChange: true)
             .AddEnvironmentVariables()
             .Build();

         var appSettingValue = config["ClientId"];

         log.LogInformation("C# HTTP trigger function processed a request.");

         //dynamic data = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(requestBody);

         ServiceBusClient serviceBusClient = new("xxxxxxxx.servicebus.windows.net",new DefaultAzureCredential());
         ServiceBusSender serviceBusSender = serviceBusClient.CreateSender("qestesting"); ;
         
         using ServiceBusMessageBatch messageBatch = await serviceBusSender.CreateMessageBatchAsync();
         messageBatch.TryAddMessage(new ServiceBusMessage(requestBody));

         try
         {
             await serviceBusSender.SendMessagesAsync(messageBatch);
         }
         finally
         {
             await serviceBusSender.DisposeAsync();
             await serviceBusClient.DisposeAsync();
         }


         ////////////////////////////////  RESPONSE
         HttpResponseMessage response = new();
         response.Headers.Add("X-AdobeSign-ClientId", appSettingValue);
         response.StatusCode = System.Net.HttpStatusCode.OK;

         return new OkObjectResult(response);
     }
 }


I am using the same code with few modification in it to send the message to Service Bus using System Managed Identity and it worked as expected.
using System.IO;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs;
using Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.Http;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;
using Azure.Messaging.ServiceBus;
using Azure.Identity;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;

namespace _78960780
{
    public static class AdobeWebhook
    {
        [FunctionName("AdobeWebhook")]
        public static async Task<IActionResult> Run(
            [HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Anonymous, "post", Route = null)] HttpRequest req,
            ILogger log)
        {
            var requestBody = string.Empty;
            using (var reader = new StreamReader(req.Body))
            {
                requestBody = reader.ReadToEnd();
            }

            var config = new ConfigurationBuilder()
             .AddJsonFile("local.settings.json", optional: true, reloadOnChange: true)
             .AddEnvironmentVariables()
             .Build();

            var appSettingValue = config["ClientId"];

            log.LogInformation("C# HTTP trigger function processed a request.");

            ServiceBusClient serviceBusClient = new("*****.servicebus.windows.net", new DefaultAzureCredential());
            ServiceBusSender serviceBusSender = serviceBusClient.CreateSender("qestesting"); ;

            using ServiceBusMessageBatch messageBatch = await serviceBusSender.CreateMessageBatchAsync();
            messageBatch.TryAddMessage(new ServiceBusMessage(requestBody));


            try
            {
                await serviceBusSender.SendMessagesAsync(messageBatch);
            }
            finally
            {
                await serviceBusSender.DisposeAsync();
                await serviceBusClient.DisposeAsync();
            }


            log.LogInformation("Message successfully sent to Service Bus.");

            // Return success response
            req.HttpContext.Response.Headers.Add("X-AdobeSign-ClientId", appSettingValue);
            req.HttpContext.Response.StatusCode = StatusCodes.Status200OK;
            return new OkObjectResult("Message successfully sent to Service Bus");
        }
    }
}

Then, I granted
Azure Service Bus Data Owner RBAC role to the function app.

I am able to send the message successfully.



I did grant my Managed Identity Data Owner rights on the bus, so I'm good there.  The only difference I see in your code is in the response, is that correct?  If my code is good, there must be a configuration at play here.

@USMC6072 Yes, I have modified the return response. Can you try once?
